# Does running Java create a new instance of JVM and a new heap each time?

Tags: java, memory, jvm, instance, heap-memory

Each time I run a Java application in my machine, am I creating an instance of the JVM? If so, am I also getting a single heap (with the size I specify) for this JVM instance and its Java application running?

Or do I have a single heap and a single JVM instance in my machine where or java applications run and reserves a heap space for their processes? If this one is true, do I have to care about a global JVM heap size when specifying the heap space to reserve for each application? I would not want to ask for more memory than the JVM has.

Comment: Why would you make your title all caps?

Comment: @BoDidely I think it will attract the Stackoverflow users :)

Comment: @SubodhJoshi yes, it attracts them to flag as VLQ and edit it

Comment: By now I would suggest trying the question again, the current status is not really helpful

Answer (score 3):

Yes, each time you run `java` you get a new JVM with its own heap.  There have been some attempts to try alternatives (for example, [IBM's multitenancy feature](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-multitenant-java/)), but none seem to have provided enough advantages to be worthwhile.